# understanding python slicing

Tags: python, string, slice

Consider the statements given below

```
pride="Working at Day"
print(pride[-2:2:-2])
```

results in

```
a agi
```

I want to understand what the outcome using [-2:2:-2].

Comment: Have you tried running it? What did you get? Was that unexpect? If so, please share what you ran, what you got, and what you expected and people can answer from there.

Comment: Try it out: https://onecompiler.com/python/3zmg4nxph

Comment: A Stack Overflow question is expected to be about "a specific problem that you actually face" while going about the practice of developing software. If you haven't _tried_ using the slice operator in the manner described, how can you have a specific problem you encountered doing so?

Comment: For questions like this just use the `repl`, i.e., in a terminal type `python` which will give you a `>>>` prompt and there you can experiment and see for yourself. By the way the outcome is `"a agi"` .